# ps2pdf error code 255

Tags: ps2pdf

I am running Winedt 10.3 along with ghostscript 9.50.  I updated all of the miktex packages.  I have installed the LaTeXify_102.  I can compile to dvi and then to ps, but when I try to use the ps2pdf command, I get the error code 255.

Here is the preamble of my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%
% Page length commands go here in the preamble

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in} % Left margin of 1 in + 0 in = 1 in

\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}   % Right margin of 8.5 in - 1 in - 6.5 in = 1 in

\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}  % Top margin of 2 in -0.75 in = 1 in

\setlength{\textheight}{9.2in}  % Lower margin of 11 in - 9 in - 1 in = 1 in

%

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 

% 1.5 denotes double spacing. Changing it will change the spacing

%

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

%

\begin{document}

\abstract{In response to an increase in blood glucose levels, insulin is released into the bloodstream by the pancreatic islets of Langerhans.  As a result of this influx of glucose, the islets start what are called bursting oscillations of the membrane potential and the intracellular calcium concentration.  Time delays of several seconds in the activity of distant cells in the islets have been observed, indicating the presence of traveling waves through the islets.}

\end{document}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Heather

Comment: Try to make a smaller but complete example that can be used for a test.

Comment: I need to include all of the preamble since I am not sure if something there is causing the problem.

Comment: @David This used to compile just fine with WinEdt version 9, so something has changed from version 9 to 10 or from the upgrade to ghostscript 9.50

Comment: @Heather this didn't compile at all as there is not document body. We can't try your document.

Comment: I have updated to a minimal code and posted it.  There are no pstricks commands and yet I still receive the same error code.

Comment: your document runs Ok with gs 9.27 I don't have 9.50 so I'll let @UlrikeFischer try that:-)

Comment: Even with the pstricks package removed I still receive the same error.  In fact, I have removed every package and still get the error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle miktex shouldn't use an external ghostscript but its own (which is imho at 9.25).

Comment: When I try to open the ps file, I received the following errors:

Failed to load C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.15\bin\gsdll64.dll, error 126
The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load C:\Program Files\Ghostgum\gsview\gsdll64.dll, error 126
The specified module could not be found.

Failed to load gsdll64.dll, error 126
The specified module could not be found.


Can't load Ghostscript DLL

Comment: What does mean "try to open the ps file"? What are you doing?

Comment: I have now upgraded to ghostscript 9.50.  I can open the postscript file, using ghostview 5.0, but I still receive the same error when I try to execute ps2pdf in winedt.  It seems like this must be an issue in the execution modes.  The ps2pdf executable is C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\ps2pdf.exe

Comment: Try on a command line. And check with `where ps2pdf` if really the miktex one is used.

Comment: The ps2pdf executable is in the directory indicated in the executable modes in winedt.  When I try to run ps2pdf File.ps I get "ps2pdf: warning: running with administrator privileges" and then no output of a pdf file.

Comment: I don't have a miktex with a multi user install and I'm not working in a account with admin privileges and I can't reproduce your problem. I suggest that you open an issue at the miktex issue tracker: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues.

Comment: I do not have a multi user install.  I am the sole user of this machine and thus the administrator.  Can you compile this using ps2pdf and if so, what do your execution modes look like?

Comment: Github was unable to assist as they indicated that it compiled for them and they were unwilling to assist in diagnosing the issue between miktex and winder.  I cannot believe no one else is having this issue.   I have uninstalled miktex, winder, ghostscript, and ghost view.  Restarted and then reinstalled.  This did not fix the issue.

Comment: The code compiles OK for me under xelatex, lualatex and pdflatex. I've got miktek on windows and the editor is Texworks. Miktek's ghostscript (\MiKTeX 2.9\ghostscript\base) has a `ps2pdf` script file dated 23-Mar-16. I don't do anything special, and I've never opened a `.ps` file. At a guess, it might be that your WinEdit is pointing to the wrong ghostscript folder.